# Angular filtering table with ng-model not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-filter

I'm trying to filter a table by one or more columns.

The problem is that there are rows in the table that do not have all fields, as they can be empty.

Then, only the rows that have all data fields are displayed before I make any search, the "ng-repeat" doesn't show this rows.

My code in HTML:

```
<input ng-show="combo.num == 0" type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="searchUS.$"/>
<input ng-show="combo.num == 1" type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="searchUS.subject"/>

<input ng-show="combo.num == 2" type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="searchUS.status"/>
<input ng-show="combo.num == 3" type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="searchUS.tags"/>


<tr ng-repeat="row in rowCollectionUserStories 
               | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse |filter:searchUS"
                ng-class="row.selectedCell ? 'cellSelectedClass' : ''">
```

I have also tried to change the ng-model = "searchUS. $" for "searchUS", but I get the input as placeholder [object] [object].

In this example it works perfectly: [link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter).

I change the array removing the number field and it works.

In my case, the field may be empty is an array, and it is the problem.

Any idea?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Wrong example link?

Comment: Yes, the link was wrong. It is already corrected.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to fix by doing the following:

```
<input ng-show="combo.num == 0" type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="searchUS.$"/>
<input ng-show="combo.num == 1" type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="searchUS.subject"/>

<input ng-show="combo.num == 2" type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="searchUS.status"/>
<input ng-show="combo.num == 3" type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="searchTags"/>


<tr ng-repeat="row in rowCollectionUserStories | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse | 
               filter: (combo.num == 3 ? {tags: searchTags} : searchUS)"
                    ng-hide="row.sprint !== undefined"
                    ng-class="row.selectedCell ? 'cellSelectedClass' : ''">
```